# How can I change the point color in densityplot (lattice)?

Tags: r

By points, I mean the points on the bottom of the densityplot. Furthermore, I would like to set some value of "jitter", such that all the points are not just on a straight line and more "scattered" around.

Comment: Show some reproducible code that illustrates what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

With lattice, it is often helpful to look at the panel version of help functions `?panel.densityplot`, which mentions `jitter.amount`; I admit to peeking at the source for panel.density to see that points are plotted using panel.xyplot, which has argument `col.symbol`. So

```
library(lattice)
x = rnorm(1000)
densityplot(x, jitter.amount=.02, col.symbol="red")
```

Comment: hey thx alot. i did look up the help funktion but im not so familiar with programming lattice graphics thus i was not sure where to put which is written in ?panel.densityplot i.e. in the panel funktion or in the densyitplot() command itself. one little thing: the jitter.amount somehow does not work:(

Comment: if it answers your question, consider (1) accepting the answer and (2) voting for it ...